# How to pass a query set to the context class in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass a queryset object to django context class, but doing so results in the following error: ***TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)***

Now i understand that the context accepts only a dictionary but i am following an example from a book called django_unleashed which uses Django version 1.8 and i am using django 2.0. and i guess it was done like that in previous versions.

So my question is how should i do this step correctly using django 2.0

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tag
from django.template import Context, loader

def homepage(request):
    tag_list = Tag.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('organizer/tag_list.html')
    context = Context({'tag_list': tag_list})
    output = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: Just `context = {'tag_list': tag_list}`.

Comment: Oh thanks, that did solve it, but can you explain why i need to remove the Context object?

Comment: Because like the error says, in recent versions `template.render` expects a plain dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you should use a regular dictionary for the context:

```
def homepage(request):
    tag_list = Tag.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('organizer/tag_list.html')
    context = {'tag_list': tag_list}
    output = template.render(context)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

In practice, you would usually use the `render` shortcut rather than manually rendering the template:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    tag_list = Tag.objects.all()
    context = {'tag_list': tag_list}
    return render(request, 'organizer/tag_list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

'''you have a model class named 'Tag',
wish your template is on ' Project directory/ app directory/ template/ same name of app directory'
example: let your project name is 'Website' and app name is 'organizer' then the template will be on: 'Website/ organizer/ templates/ organizer/ tag_list.html' Confirm your TEMPLATES setting is default on setting.py file."'

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Tag 
def homepage(request):
    tag_list  = Tag.objects.all()
    context =  { 'tag_list' : tag_list}
    return render ( request, 'organizer/tag_list.html', context)
```